# How to use a particular schema in Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am currently working on CLI of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64).

When I write the command `sp_databases` then it lists all the databases present. I am experienced with MySQL which has a command called `use (databaseName)` which actually selects a particular database, so that we can work on it.

Is there such a command for Microsoft SQL Server, where I can select a particular database and go inside ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use `USE`

```
USE DatabaseName
GO

...query...
```

You can also use a 3 part name when calling tables

```
SELECT *
FROM DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName
```